# Schema changes from int to List of Int in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, c#-4.0, mongodb-.net-driver

My requirement is to change Mongodb schema for a property of type integer to list of integer. In production, Mongodb has already data in integer format. I want to support data in both format i.e. integer as well as list of integer.

My Model was like below

```
Public class TObj
{   
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public int AType {get; set;}
   public Sam SamObj {get; set;}
}
```

I want model to be like below

```
 Public class TObj
{   
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public **List<int>** AType {get; set;}
   public Sam SamObj {get; set;}
}
```

How can I achieve to store new model in mongo as well as fetch older model from mongo database.

Regards,
Amit